# Storing returned data from SQL into Asp:Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using a SQL SELECT string to return all values in database when a rows status is a certain value. I'm then storing this information into a label. My problem is when I select everything without the "WHERE status=2" part everything works great, but when I try to specify that my label only holds a single value instead of a list.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM HonApp.dbo.apps WHERE status=2";

..create sql data reader here..

myReader.Read();
if (myReader.HasRows)
  {
     while (myReader.Read())
  {
     emailList.Text += myReader[5].ToString() + ", ";
  }
}
```

I think what is happening is that instead of iterating through and appending each email it is simply overwriting the label each time. Any ideas where I could be wrong?

NOTE: It is working without the "WHERE status" part but it returns all values from the database; I only want the emails where the status is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `myReader.Read()` before `while` loop,this will skip your first record.So if there is one record with the given id then you are basically ignoring it and that's why you don't see anything in the label.You should remove that line.Your `while` loop is fine, since you are using `+=` that will not overwrite your value.If there is one or more record with the given id  (2 in this case) it should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I was thinking you had to call .Read() before you can do the .HasRows

Comment: @Jobokai no that's not necessary :)